# Expansion a 2 dimension variable by using Taylor series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The **Taylor Series** for a variable ($F$) can be written as :

$F = F_0+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \Delta t + \frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2} \Delta t^2+\cdots$

The variables $F_x$ and $F_y$ are functions to $(x, y, \dot{x}, \dot{y})$, By using **Taylor series** the expansion yield:

[image]

where: $k_{xx} = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}, k_{xy} = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y},\cdots, k_{x20}^{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial x^2},k_{x20}^{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial x\partial y},\cdots$ .

$~~~~~~~~~~~~d_{xx} = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial \dot{x}}, d_{xy} = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial \dot{y}},\cdots, d_{x20}^{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial \dot{x}^2},d_{x20}^{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial \dot{x} \partial \dot{y}},\cdots$ .

I tried to get the previous results but I couldn't, especially for the term $k_{x20}^{xx}$ which does not multiplied by 2 and $d_{x20}^{xx}$ does!!!

I need to know, how the expansion done for $F_x$ and $ F_y$?

Comment: Doesn't the factor of two show up from the commutativity of the derivatives? $\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial x \partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial \dot{x} \partial x} $

Comment: @KitterCatter - Could you explain how to get the term $\frac {\partial ^2 F_x} {\partial x \partial \dot {x}}$?

Comment: Misread your notation. Why does $d_{x20} ^{xx}$ have a factor of $x\dot{x}$ when it corresponds to a second derivative of F with respect to $\dot{x}$? That seems off...

Comment: You might get some value in your generalization of multivariate functions by looking up the Hessian matrix. Especially since you are treating the x and y components independently.